# Encoding problems with gridview source xml

Tags: c#, xml, gridview

I'm reading a XML file into a Dataset. This works fine and umlauts (äöü) are correct. 
Now I set the datasource for my gridview to the dataset and now the umlauts are incorrect (ä -> `&#228;`). So how can I set the gridview datasource to utf-8?

```
DataSet auf = new DataSet();
auf.ReadXml(MapPath("App_Data/test.xml"));
gv_auf.DataSource = auf.Tables["Jobs"];
gv_auf.DataBind();
```

test.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<Config>
<Jobs id="1" dateiname="tempä.txt" />
</Config>
```

Data in Dataset -> tempä:

```
foreach (DataRow dr in auf.Tables[0].Rows)
{
string name = dr[1].ToString();
}
```

After setting the datasource for the gridview -> `tem&#228;`:

```
foreach (GridViewRow gvr in gv_auf.Rows) 
{
string name = gvr.Cells[1].Text;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got the solution:

Add in web.config

```
<globalization requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" culture="de-DE" uiCulture="de-DE" />
```

Add the gridview event

```
onrowdatabound="gv_auf_RowDataBound"
```

And finally the code for the onwowdatabound event

```
foreach (TableCell cell in e.Row.Cells)
        {
            cell.Text = Server.HtmlDecode(cell.Text);
        }
```